# Unable to execute Embedded Neo4j 2.2 Cypher Queries from Java

Tags: neo4j

Recently I upgraded to Neo4j 2.2 and I am trying to run Neo4j's examples JavaQuery.java from the reference manual http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html I am getting the below exception. All necessary neo4j 2.2 jars are in classpath.

I could run cypher queries for embedded Neo4j from Java very well in 2.1.7. Please suggest a workaround. I have already upgraded my graph database and cannot go back to 2.1.7. I am running on Windows 7 + jdk 7

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No     query engine installed.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.NoQueryEngine.noQueryEngine(NoQueryEngine.java:56)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.NoQueryEngine.executeQuery(NoQueryEngine.java:33)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.execute(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:953)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.execute(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:944)
at JavaQuery.run(JavaQuery.java:67)
at JavaQuery.main(JavaQuery.java:47)
```

Comment: Is `neo4j-cypher-<version>.jar` and all of its dependencies on the classpath (see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-cypher/2.2.1) ?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster Hi Stefan, could you please upload your entire classpath screenshot. It used to work with jdk 7 + neo4j 2.1.7, After I upgraded to neo4j 2.2 and the new neo4j + cypher jars I am getting the exception
Here is my classpath screenshot
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=160rcr9&s=8#.VTZYbSvF-So

Answer (score 0):

I tested the same code on Windows 7 successfully. Ensure the classpath is correct.

Comment: Could you please upload your entire classpath screenshot. It used to work with Win 7+ jdk 7 + neo4j 2.1.7, After upgrade to neo4j 2.2 and the new neo4j + cypher 2.2 jars I am getting the exception
Here is my classpath screenshot
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=160rcr9&s=8#.VTZYbSvF-So